# Application log4j.properties not loaded

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I have a clean tomcat 7 installation on amazon linux (version 201303) with one application deployed as ROOT. log4j-1.2.17.jar resides in WEB-INF/lib. There is a log4j.properties file in WEB-INF/classes containing the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1, A2

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n

log4j.appender.A2.File=${catalina.home}/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=99
log4j.appender.A2.Append=true

log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n
```

In the app, log4j is instantiated with

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName());
```

app.log never gets created. If I create it manually, it is never written to. The only logging going on is in logs/catalina.out. What am I missing? I've read through http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html several times. The following excerpt seems to confirm my approach:

> These steps are not needed if you just want to use log4j in your own web application. — In that case, just put log4j.jar and log4j.properties into WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes of your web application.

There is a log4j.jar and log4j.xml in catalina_home/lib, along with a log4j.properties in catalina_home/conf. Could those be conflicting with the jars included in my WAR? I don't see any errors in catalina.out.

**UPDATE**

So it appears that the log4j.properties in WEB-INF/classes is loading. I removed the ConsoleAppender (log4j.appender.A1) and log messages stopped appearing in catalina.out. I put it back in and the log messages reappeared in catalina.out. What's weird is the conversion pattern doesn't seem to match the log. Shouldn't `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n` generate something like `2013-07-10 INFO ClassName Log message`? Instead I'm seeing `14:39:29,180 INFO  [ClassName] Log message`.

**UPDATE 2**

I found my answer. There was a log4j.xml in ${catalina.home}/lib that was configuring log4j at the container level. I guess if I actually new what I was doing in Tomcat I would have figured it out sooner. Once I started configuring lib/log4j.xml I got the expected result. I'm still a little confused why my app inherited that configuration instead of using its own log4j.properties. Oh well, I achieved the intended result so time to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a log4j.xml in ${catalina.home}/lib that was configuring log4j at the container level. We only have one app deployed, so using lib/log4j.xml works well for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this ( first test with physical path for log file ) and try with different version of log4j jar

Jar Version log4j-1.2.14.jar

> log4j.watch=true
>
> log4j.readtime=30000
>
> log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, applicationlogging
>   log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, strutslogging
>   log4j.category.applicationlogging = DEBUG, applicationlogging
>   log4j.category.org = DEBUG, strutslogging
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG
>   log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=OFF
>   log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=OFF
>   log4j.additivity.applicationlogging = false
>   log4j.additivity.strutslogging = false
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.File= C:/logs/app.log
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.MaxFileSize=3000KB
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.MaxBackupIndex=50
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n

Comment: There is no "main properties file" for this app. log4j.properties is the only properties file used by this app.

Comment: I figured it out finally. log4j was getting configured at the container level, before my app was initialized. Thanks for attempting to help me.